# Как сгруппировать файлы по родительскому каталогу

Tags: c#

Получаю рекурсивно `jpg`-файлы, но почему то группировка по родительским папкам работает некорректно. Подскажите в чем причина

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\1\Documents\EX","*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).GroupBy(x => Directory.GetParent(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: `работает некорректно` что это значит?

Comment: не группирует @tym32167

Comment: а с чего вы решили, что `DirectoryInfo` реализует свой `Equals`? Попробуйте `x => Directory.GetParent(x)` ==> `x => Directory.GetParent(x).FullName`

Comment: Проблема решена? Ведь `GetParent(x).FullName` - рабочий вариант (зря Алексей удалил ответ).